# How to properly use radioGroup?

Tags: grails, radio-button

I have a problem regarding the implementation of my radioGroup. If I selected one of the options, and clicked the button "Apply Changes", the success message is shown, but the value that I have chosen is unselected, which seems that I haven't selected any values from my radioGroup at all. This is my code:

```
<cm:fieldRow required="true" label="Nature of employment" hint="" bean="${employmentInfo}" field="employmentNature.id">
    <g:radioGroup name="employmentNature.id" values="${EmploymentNature.list().id}" labels="${EmploymentNature.list().title}">
        ${it.radio} ${it.label}<br/>
    </g:radioGroup>
</cm:fieldRow>
```

When I haven't selected any of the values from the radioGroup, and clicked on the "Add Changes" button, the error message that I have set is not showing.Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make use of the `value` attribute for [`g:radioGroup`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/radioGroup.html). Without a `value` attribute, the tag doesn't know which radio should be checked.